# Point cloud registration in PCL using precomputed features

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm planning on doing a registration between two clouds using RANSAC in PCL and I already have features computed from another program. Can I somehow load these features into PCL to use for the registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take PCL's [prerejective alignment tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/alignment_prerejective.php) as an example that uses FPFH features and adapt it.

The code below (extracted from the tutorial) defines the feature type, computes it and passes to the alignment object.

```
typedef pcl::FPFHSignature33 FeatureT;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<FeatureT> FeatureCloudT;
FeatureCloudT::Ptr scene_features (new FeatureCloudT);
...
fest.compute (*scene_features);
...
pcl::SampleConsensusPrerejective<PointNT,PointNT,FeatureT> align;
align.setTargetFeatures (scene_features);
```

The third template argument for `pcl::SampleConsensusPrerejective` is the feature type (in the example `pcl::FPFHSignature33`). So all we need to do is to replace it with some custom feature type.

This is quite easy thanks to the [Histogram point type](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php). To define an N-dimensional feature point type:

```
typedef pcl::Histogram<N> FeatureT;
FeatureT feature_vector;
```

`feature_vector.histogram` is a float[N] array.